# Does wxwidgets use rosetta in Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, wxwidgets

While deciding for a cross platform language for a desktop application I want to do, I came across "wxwidgets" for C++. After testing a demo application in Mac 10.6.4 I noticed the application needed "Rosetta" to run.

My concern is: Will I always need "Rosetta" for a C++ application with wxwidgets to run on a Mac?

Note: Latest news about Mac dropping support for Java in future OS release (hoping Oracle will pickup were left) and the upcoming App Desktop Store will not support apps requiring Rosetta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Universe Binaries with wxWidgets. My guess is that your demo application was only compiled for PPC. (Which seems weird, actually. Was the app you tried one you built yourself from examples/, or just one you downloaded off the web?).

I've built Universal apps in wxWidgets both in Xcode (the easiest way to do it), and I believe it's not that hard with a Makefile on the command line. (you make the ppc version, make the intel version, and use the `lipo` command line tool to squash them together.)

Comment: The demo app I downloaded from the samples apps they provide on their site, I have no way to tell how it was compiled. Your explanation makes a lot of sense. As you read in my question I am planning in a cross platform application, in order for me to compile a Windows version will I need to compile it in Windows using Dev C++ or Visual Studio?

Comment: redhatlab: correct: you'd need to get Dev C++ or Visual Studio and build on Windows for your Windows builds